# how to update-in ingoring the first level in clojure

Tags: clojure

When use update-in we need to provide the full path to an element. But what if I want to update ALL elements whose second level key is :MaxInclude

e.g the input is

```
(def a  {:store {:type "varchar"},
 :amount {:nullable true, :length nil, :type "float", :MaxInclude "100.02"},
:unit {:type "int"},
:unit-uniform {:type "int" :MaxInclude "100"}
})
```

the required output is (convert MaxInclude from string to float/int based on theie type):

```
{:store {:type "varchar"},
 :amount {:nullable true, :length nil, :type "float", :MaxInclude 100.02},
:unit {:type "int"},
:unit-uniform {:type "int" :MaxInclude 100}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was thinking it would be nice to have a function like `update-in` that matches on key predicate functions instead of exact key values. This is what I came up with:

```
(defn update-all
  "Like update-in except the second parameter is a vector of predicate
  functions taking keys as arguments. Updates all values contained at a
  matching path. Looks for keys in maps only."
  [m [key-pred & key-preds] update-fn]
  (if (map? m)
    (let [matching-keys (filter key-pred (keys m))
          f (fn [acc k]
              (update-in acc [k] (if key-preds
                                   #(update-all %
                                                key-preds
                                                update-fn)
                                   update-fn)))]
      (reduce f m matching-keys))
    m))
```

With this in place, all you need to do is:

```
(update-all a [= #{:MaxInclude}] read-string)
```

The `=` is used as the first key matching function because it always returns true when passed one argument. The second is using the fact that a set is a function. This function uses non-optimised recursion but the call stack will only be as deep as the number of matching map levels.

Answer (score 1):

```
(into {}
      (map (fn [[k v]]
             {k (if (contains? v :MaxInclude)
                  (update-in v [:MaxInclude] read-string)
                  v)})
           a))
```

Here I am mapping over the key-value pairs and destructuring each into k and v. Then I use `update-in` on the value if it contains `:MaxInclude`. Finally, I pour the pairs from a list `into` a hash map.

Notes:

- This will error on `contains?` if any of the main map's values are not indexed collections.
- I use `read-string` as a convenient way to convert the string to a number in the same way the Clojure reader would do when compiling the string that is your number literal. There may be disadvantages to this approach.